# Hide cursor in textbox

Tags: javascript

I placed two textboxes at the same position of the web page using z-index.

When page is loaded, the cursor will focus in the enabled textbox that is located under the disabled textbox.

Firefox shows only the disabled textbox and doesn't show the cursor.

My problem is that IE shows both disabled textbox and the cursor in the enabled textbox.

I want to show only the disabled textbox in my webpage.
Is there any way to hide the cursor in IE?

It is sample coding...

```
<script>

   function FocusOnInput(){
       document.getElementById("hidden").focus();
    }

    function show(field){
        var value = field.value;
        alert(value);
    }

</script>

<body onload="FocusOnInput()">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="securityNo"
         name="txtsecurityNo" value=""
         size="30" style="position: absolute;z-index: 0" 
                 disabled="disabled"/>

      <input type="text" id="hidden"
         name="txthidden" value=""                      
         onchange="show(this);" style="left: 0px;z-index: -1;"/>        
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar He wants to prevent blinking cursor if focused a disabled textarea, now that's what I've understood :P

Comment: Please show us the source code.

Comment: Do you mean the caret?

Comment: LoL. @Mr.Alien Surely not the caret I suppose.

Comment: The cursor is the arrow you move around the screen, it's probably the caret! Otherwise you can hide the cursor with CSS when hovering the textbox ;-) ....

Comment: @Mr.Alien yes, I want to prevent blinking cursor if focused a disabled textbox.

Comment: @PraveenKumar See I told you ;)

Comment: This seems more of a browser feature / issue. Dude, move on... :)

Comment: I don't get why you have two text fields on top of each other in the first place.

Comment: Have you considered using `type="password"` instead? You're going to run into a lot of problems with the current implementation.

Comment: @Juhana enabled textbox will get data from qrcode scanner and send the data to server. When server will send data back, Disabled textbox will receive. Reason is I don't want to show data in the enabled textbox when scanning by qrcode scanner.

Comment: Yeah, there are probably dozens of better ways to handle that. Use a password field, or make the field zero pixels wide/high, or use a hidden field where you copy input, ...

Comment: @Juhana yes, you are right and thanks a lot. I make the field zero pixels wide/high and it is ok for me now. :)

Comment: Just to clarify those ragging down on the "cursor" - back in the old DOS and command-line UNIX systems, *the cursor* was what you kids now call "caret". So stop it.